# Featured image suggestion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Didn't see it suggested or asked: why is the feature image not in a 3:2 ratio that is pretty much standard for images? It's literally a handful of pixels off on the y-axis and so you're forced into a crop that may spoil the original composition. This doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: If it's a site design issue, I would gladly help to fix it. I do web design, so I doubt changing a layout like this would be any trouble at all.

Comment: 375x210 seems somewhat arbitrary, though it is "nearly" 16:9, but I agree 3:2 might be better.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we've been using this ratio for a number of months, I think it is working well - some of the photos that have been image of the week have been awesome. As such, I don't think it's too much of a problem - sure, some pictures might not work, but some don't work in 3:2 either.